# InvalidArgumentException when creating model through artisan

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to Laravel and is encountering a problem when I start a new laravel project.
My current environment is: PHP 7.4.14 on Linux (Manjaro) & Composer 2.0.9.

I use the following command to initialize a laravel project:

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel lara "5.x"
```

Then I switch to the directory of lara and type:

```
./artisan make:controller ArticleController --resource -model=Article
```

And then, I got an InvalidArgumentException: Model name contains invalid characters.

```
   InvalidArgumentException  : Model name contains invalid characters.

  at $HOME/WS/php/lara/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Console/ControllerMakeCommand.php:159
155|      */
156|     protected function parseModel($model)
157|     {
158|         if (preg_match('([^A-Za-z0-9_/\\\\])', $model)) {
159|             throw new InvalidArgumentException('Model name contains invalid characters.');
160|         }
161| 
162|         $model = trim(str_replace('/', '\\', $model), '\\');
163|
```

I am confused and dunno what I have done wrong so I would like to seek your helps.
Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: `php artisan make:controller ArticleController` is the command. You get that error by requesting the website or on the shell?

Comment: I get it on the shell

Comment: Thanks very much. Your suggestion works brilliantly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`php artisan make:controller PhotoController --resource --model=Photo`

it should be "--model". The parameters are prefixed with double "-"!

[More](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers)

You can also use the shortened syntax

`php artisan make:controller PhotoController --resource -m Photo`